# PyIlnstallerによって単一実行ファイル化したアプリケーションでpydubを利用したい

Tags: python, python3, macos, ffmpeg, pyinstaller

TkInterを用いてGUIを表示するPythonファイル(myapp.py)をPyInstallerによって単一実行ファイル(myapp.app)にしました。そのmyapp.pyでPydubを利用しようとしましたが、次のように実行したところ、エラーがログに出力されました。

#### myapp.py内でのPydubのコード

```py
segument = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(file_path)
```

#### エラー

```
[Error 2]No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'
```

調べると、Pydubではffmpegをsubprocessで利用しているようでした。
ちなみに、myapp.pyをそのまま実行すれば、エラーは出ません

### 環境

MacOS 10.15.7

Python 3.6
PyInstaller 3.6
FFmpeg 4.3.1
Pydub 0.24.1

### 試したこと①

myapp.py内でffmpegやffprobeをsubprocessモジュールを用いて実行しているので、PyInstallerでこれらのファイルをmyapp.appにバンドルしています。そのためmyapp.app/Contents/MacOS/内にffmpegやffprobeのバイナリファイルがあります。そこでこれらのファイルパスをPydubに教えることで解消できるのではないかと考えました。

[pydubのGitHub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)
pydubをgitで確認すると、以下のような記述がありました。

> #### pydub/audio_segment.py

```py
class AudioSegment(object):
# --略--
    converter = get_encoder_name()  # either ffmpeg or avconv
# --略--
```

> #### pydub/utils.py

```py
# --略--
def get_encoder_name():
    """
    Return enconder default application for system, either avconv or ffmpeg
    """
    if which("avconv"):
        return "avconv"
    elif which("ffmpeg"):
        return "ffmpeg"
    else:
        # should raise exception
        warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
        return "ffmpeg"
# --略--
```

そこでpydub.AudioSegmentクラスのconverterを設定してあげれば良いと考え、先述したコードの前に次のコードを追加しましたが、同じエラーが表示され解決できませんでした。(APP_PATHはmyapp.appのパスの文字列)

```py
pydub.AudioSegment.converter = APP_PATH + '/Contents/MacOS/ffmpeg' # 追加
segument = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(file_path)
```

また、pydub/audio_segment.pyのAudioSegmentクラス内に次のようなメソッドがありましたが、使い方がわかりませんでした。

> #### pydub/audio_segment.py

```
class AudioSegment(object):
#--略--
    # TODO: remove in 1.0 release
    # maintain backwards compatibility for ffmpeg attr (now called converter)
    @classproperty
    def ffmpeg(cls):
        return cls.converter

    @ffmpeg.setter
    def ffmpeg(cls, val):
        cls.converter = val
# --略--
```

### 試したこと②

sys.path.appendを用いてpydubにffmpegやffprobeのパスを教えようとしましたが、同じエラーが表示され、解決できませんでした。

```py
sys.path.append(APP_PATH + '/Contents/MacOS/ffmpeg')
sys.path.append(APP_PATH + '/Contents/MacOS/ffprobe')
```

Comment: `PyInstaller`の有無で`sys.path.append()`の結果を`print()`して違いを確かめてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: [こちらのサイト](https://teratail.com/questions/308491)のようにさせていただきました。コメントしていただきありがとうございます。